# What languages does EVE speak?

Tags: languages, wall-e

In *Wall-E* there is a scene where E.V.E asks Wall-E what his "directive" is, but she first asks it in three different languages; **what are those languages that E.V.E speaks?**

Are they human languages, or are they alien?

Comment: The real question is, why doesn't she speak English to begin with, but that's another story.

Comment: They're all Earth languages, so it wouldn't be unreasonable to start with any of them. Also, unless I've forgotten something (it happens), there's no conclusive proof that the story takes place in America, we just assume so because WALL-E understands English (Obviously, that wouldn't be the case when the film is dubbed into other languages). It could be that in this future, the world is far more homogeneous - there's McDonalds in almost every country now.

Comment: Useful to keep in mind that EVE's is just to collect samples and return. There was no strong expectation that EVE would encounter anything that needed to be communicated with (WALL-E's presence there is unusual, and only because the little robot has managed to maintain himself for so long), so her communication skills are limited. She seems to be improvising her sounds, as if she's repurposing mechanisms that produce sounds into words since WALL-E can't understand her otherwise. Her algorithm for selecting languages to try is probably almost random.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html) indicates that they're German (["*Weisung*"](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/Weisung.html)), Japanese (["*Meirei - 命令*"](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/japanese-english/%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4)) and Swahili ("[*Maelekezo*](http://mymemory.translated.net/en/Swahili/English/maelekezo)")

> **EVE** (hums): *[So what's your story?]*
>
> Wall-E falls backwards with surprise. 
>   *[Me?]*
>
> Eve scrolls through a variety of languages:
>
> **EVE:** (German)
>   *[Directive?]*
>   (Japanese)
>   *[Directive?]*
>
> **WALL-E:** *[Huh?]*
>
> **EVE:** (Swahili)
>   *[Directive?]*
>   (English)
>   *Directive?*
>
> **WALL-E** (beeps): *[Oh, I understand that!]*

Comment: Weisung, Meirei, and no idea what the spelling on the last one is.

Comment: @Terriblefan - My German and Japanese were up to the task but my Swahili is very rusty. I had to go and look it up.

Comment: Apparently it's "Instructions" translated. Just like Weisung is actually "reason" (and a loan word from Latin languages).

Comment: @Terriblefan - Literally "**command/directive**" in German, "**order/directive**" in Japanese and something like "**Instructions**" in Swahili.